# Preserving Session State between IONIC 3 http.post requests

Tags: http, ionic3, http-post, session-state

I am having multiple http.post requests in an IONIC 3 project. I need to preserve the session state between the calls. The way I am calling the server is as follows:

```
this.http.post('http://192.168.1.107:7777/mobile/Open_a').
subscribe(
  (data:any) => 
  {

// first processing data for the first call here.
// next calling the server for the second time and passing the data back to the server

// start of second call
this.http.post('http://192.168.1.107:7777/mobile/Open_b',
  {params: {clientdata:"test data"}}).
  subscribe((data2:any)=>
  {
      console.log(data2);
  },
  err2 =>
  {
    console.log('error happened!');
    console.log(err2.message);
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Connection error',
      subTitle: err2.message,
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }
  );
  // end of second call code},


 err =>
  {
    console.log('error happened!');
    console.log(err.message);
    ProductDataProvider.ItemsLoaded=true;
    ProductDataProvider.IsLoading=false;
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Connection error',
      subTitle: err.message,
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  }

);
```

the problem is that both calls to the server work, but the session state is not preserved. Could anybody point out what I am doing wrong?

any advice is highly appreciated.

yours sincrely

Comment: you mean you want to always query your sql?

Comment: Nope, I don't want the server to open a new session for every time i use a post request. I want the client to be on the same session.

Answer (score 0):

just use withCredetials:true

this.http.post(ProductDataProvider.Server+'/mobile/index',{ search:searchstr},{ withCredentials:true})...